Why the marker (text) is not movable with polygon?
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { GoogleMap, DrawingManager, Polygon, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { openDialog } from 'app/store/fuse/dialogSlice';
import { ConfirmDialog } from 'app/components/ConfirmDialog';
import { Box, Button } from '@mui/material';

const Map: React.FC = () => {
    const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState<Array<Array<{ lat: number; lng: number }>>>([]);
    const [polygonLabels, setPolygonLabels] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onPolygonComplete = (polygon: google.maps.Polygon) => {
        dispatch(
            openDialog({
                children: (
                    <ConfirmDialog
                        title="You're sure?"
                        description="You want to add new venue?"
                        onConfirm={() => {
                            const paths = polygon
                                .getPaths()
                                .getArray()
                                .map((path) =>
                                    path.getArray().map((latLng) => ({ lat: latLng.lat(), lng: latLng.lng() }))
                                );

                            setPolygons((prevPolygons) => [...prevPolygons, ...paths]);

                            // Add a dummy label for the new polygon
                            setPolygonLabels((prevLabels) => [...prevLabels, 'Venue']);
                        }}
                    />
                )
            })
        );
    };

    const onOverlayComplete = (e: google.maps.drawing.OverlayCompleteEvent) => {
        const newPolygon = e.overlay as google.maps.Polygon;
        newPolygon.setMap(null);
    };

    const undo = () => {
        const newPolygonList = [...polygons];
        newPolygonList.pop();
        setPolygons(newPolygonList);

        const newLabelList = [...polygonLabels];
        newLabelList.pop();
        setPolygonLabels(newLabelList);
    };

    const deletePolygon = () => {
        dispatch(
            openDialog({
                children: (
                    <ConfirmDialog
                        title="You're sure?"
                        description="You want to delete these records?"
                        onConfirm={() => {}}
                    />
                )
            })
        );
    };

    return (
        <GoogleMap
            center={{ lat: polygons?.[0]?.[0].lat ?? 0, lng: polygons?.[0]?.[0].lng ?? 0 }}
            zoom={5}
            mapContainerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
            options={{}}
        >

            <div className="flex justify-center">

                <DrawingManager
                    onPolygonComplete={onPolygonComplete}
                    options={{
                        drawingControl: true,
                        drawingControlOptions: {
                            drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON],
                            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
                        },

                        polygonOptions: {
                            editable: true,
                            draggable: true
                        }
                    }}
                    onOverlayComplete={onOverlayComplete}
                />
            </div>

            {polygons?.map((polygon, index) => (
                <>
                    <Polygon
                        key={index}
                        paths={polygon}
                        onClick={deletePolygon}
                        options={{
                            draggable: true,
                            editable: true,
                            fillColor: 'red'
                        }}
                    />
                    <Marker
                        key={`marker-${index}`}
                        draggable
                        position={{
                            lat: polygon.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.lat, 0) / polygon.length,
                            lng: polygon.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.lng, 0) / polygon.length
                        }}
                        label={{
                            text: polygonLabels[index],
                            color: 'white'
                        }}
                        icon="undefined"
                    />
                </>
            ))}
        </GoogleMap>
    );
};

export default Map;


I am working on react google maps api library. I have successfully implemented functionality that allows users to draw and move polygons on the map. However, I'm encountering an issue where, after moving a completed polygon to a new position, a marker (text) that indicates the center of the polygon does not update its position and remains at the initial location of the polygon.

On your Marker component position prop, have you tried passing a setPosition() function that updates whenever you move your polygon?
